# Commandlink primefaces update + js execution before update without actionlistener

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have command link:

```
<p:commandlink onclick = 'someJsMethod()' update ='form'/>
```

As I stated in the title I need to execute js Method before I update my form without actionListener.

Will it work as I written or I need to write something else?

Comment: `onstart` would be a safer way to do it.

Comment: @tt_emrah provide this as answer and let him accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onstart` is the correct attribute to use here, since it runs before the ajax request is sent.